# Docker - Windows 10 MINGW64 - OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: git, docker

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.13

RUN apt-get install wget
RUN pip install pandas sqlalchemy psycopg2

WORKDIR /app
COPY ingest_data.py ingest_data.py 

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "ingest_data.py" ]
```

ingest_data.py:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import argparse

from time import time

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def main(params):
    user = params.user
    password = params.password
    host = params.host 
    port = params.port 
    db = params.db
    table_name = params.table_name
    url = params.url
    
    # the backup files are gzipped, and it's important to keep the correct extension
    # for pandas to be able to open the file
    if url.endswith('.csv.gz'):
        csv_name = 'output.csv.gz'
    else:
        csv_name = 'output.csv'

    os.system(f"wget {url} -O {csv_name}")

    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}')

    df_iter = pd.read_csv(csv_name, iterator=True, chunksize=100000)

    df = next(df_iter)

    df.tpep_pickup_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_pickup_datetime)
    df.tpep_dropoff_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_dropoff_datetime)

    df.head(n=0).to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace')

    df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append')


    while True: 

        try:
            t_start = time()
            
            df = next(df_iter)

            df.tpep_pickup_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_pickup_datetime)
            df.tpep_dropoff_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_dropoff_datetime)

            df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append')

            t_end = time()

            print('inserted another chunk, took %.3f second' % (t_end - t_start))

        except StopIteration:
            print("Finished ingesting data into the postgres database")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ingest CSV data to Postgres')

    parser.add_argument('--user', required=True, help='user name for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--password', required=True, help='password for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--host', required=True, help='host for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--port', required=True, help='port for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--db', required=True, help='database name for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--table_name', required=True, help='name of the table where we will write the results to')
    parser.add_argument('--url', required=True, help='url of the csv file')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

When I execute in my git bash the following code, it doesn't work:

```
URL="https://github.com/DataTalksClub/nyc-tlc-data/releases/download/yellow/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.csv.gz"
winpty python3 ingest_data.py \
    --user=root \
    --password=root \
    --host=localhost \
    --port=5431 \
    --db=ny_taxi \
    --table_name=yellow_taxi_trips \
    --url=${URL}
```

It says:

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/wgetrc
--2024-01-22 08:38:16--  https://github.com/DataTalksClub/nyc-tlc-data/releases/download/yellow/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.csv.gz
Resolving github.com... 140.82.121.3
Connecting to github.com|140.82.121.3|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DE-ZoomCamp\week_1_basics_n_setup\2_docker_sql\ingest_data.py", line 78, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "D:\DE-ZoomCamp\week_1_basics_n_setup\2_docker_sql\ingest_data.py", line 33, in main
    df_iter = pd.read_csv(csv_name, iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.
py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\reader
s.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\reader
s.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\reader
s.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\reader
s.py", line 1235, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Armut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_pars
er_wrapper.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 551, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Someone an idea? I asked ChatGPT many times, but his suggestions didn't work for me.
seems for me the issue comes from SSL. I already installed OpenSSL the latest version but still it don't work.

................................................................................................

Comment: This seems to be the same issue. If you have updated your OpenSSL, then try updating wget. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479823/can-not-download-from-an-https-site-ssl-with-wget

Comment: @HansKilian The `Dockerfile` is `FROM python:3.9.13` which is Debian 11. Should be fresh enough.

Comment: If you're running your script in Git Bash, as you say, then I don't understand how Docker is relevant